# About intervals of confidence

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

Suppose that $T_1$ is a $\alpha*100\%$ lower confidence limit for $\theta$ and $T_2$ is a $\alpha*100\%$ upper confidence limit for $\theta$.Further assume that $P(T_1<T_2)=1$. Find a $(2\alpha-1)*100\%$ confidence interval for $\theta$

I thought that $(T_1,T_2)$ was a $ {\alpha}^2*100\%$ confidence interval, but it is only if $T_1,T_2$ are independents (correct?)

Answer (score 0):

Your statement about $\alpha^2$ looks peculiar given that you know $P(T_1<T_2)=1$.

The events $T_1 \gt \theta$ and $T_2 \lt \theta$ are not independent, since if $T_1 \gt \theta$ then $\Pr(T_2 \lt \theta)=0$.  Indeed $T_1 \gt \theta$ and $T_2 \lt \theta$ are almost surely mutually exclusive

Hint: You should reconsider $\Pr(T_1 \le \theta \le T_2)$ in the light of this

Comment: $P(T_1\leq\theta\leq T_2)=P(T_1\leq\theta,\theta\leq T_2)=P(T_1\leq \theta)P(\theta\leq T_2)=\alpha*\alpha$ assuming the independence of $T_1$ and $T_2$, whatever the main problem is not it, and I think the event $T_1>\theta$ does not imply $T_1>T_2$

Comment: @TheHillbillyCat What do you think is the value of $\Pr(T_1\gt\theta,\theta\gt T_2)$?  How does this compare with $\Pr(T_1\gt\theta)\Pr(\theta\gt T_2)$?

Comment: Well  $P(T_1>\theta,T_2>\theta)=0$ by the assumption, but it its distinct to $P(T_1>\theta)P(\theta>T_2)$ and in fact $P(T_1>\theta)P(\theta>T_2)=(1-\alpha)*(1-\alpha)$, I have thought about the problem and reached the conclusion that $T_1,T_2$ are nor independent